# python pyqt5 tab contents not displaying

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt5

I am using PYQT5 to make an GUI application which will have 2 tabs. On one tab ('tImp') I want to use a file browser, on the other tab (tRec) I want to have a push button. I have coded what I want to see on the tab, but when I execute the script, I see the tabs, but not the contents (file browser and push button). Below is what I have so far:

```
import sys from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Budget'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 40
        self.width = 1200
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.table_widget = MyTableWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.show()

class MyTableWidget(QWidget):     

    def __init__(self, parent):   
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tImp = QWidget()   
        self.tRec = QWidget()
        self.tabs.resize(1200,600) 

        # Create Import tab
        def tImp():
            self.tImp.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.tImp.layout.addWidget(self.openFileNamesDialog)
            self.tImp.setLayout(self.tImp.layout)

        # Create file browser Widget        
        def openFileNamesDialog(self):    
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
            files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "","All Files (*);;Format Files (*.csv)", options=options)
            if files:
                print(files)     

        # Create Reconcile tab
        def tRec():
            self.tRec.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            self.pushButton1 = QPushButton("Commit")
            self.tRec.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton1)
            self.tRec.setLayout(self.tRec.layout)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tImp,"Import")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tRec,"Reconcile")

        # Add tabs to widget        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined functions called `tImp()` and `tRec()` to set up the widgets but you never call these functions.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm a bit new to OO programming (as you can probably tell). I created 'def tImp', then under the section "#Add tabs" and I thought that the line "self.tabs.addTab(self.**tImp**,"Import")" would have called the function. I added "tRec()" to the end of the "# Add tabs to widget " section and that seems to work. (Although my tImp() is having issues to for some other reason ... but that's for another post)

Comment: Note that `self.tImp` is not the same as the `tImp` function you created.  On an earlier line you did `self.tImp = QWidget()`.  That is what `self.tImp` is.  `tImp` is just a local variable holding a function that is never called.